# Microsoft Excel 2007 conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have created a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet where in each cell there is a formula which gives a value with two decimals. I need to use the conditional formatting to highlight the cells in which the second decimal is 0, and it would be great if I also could highlight the cells which both decimals are 0 in a different way.

Thank you very much in advance for your assistance, best wishes

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of what your data will look like?

Answer (score 0):

-Highlight the range you would like to use for your conditional formatting.
-Click the Home tab, then Conditional Formatting then New Formatting Rule.
 
-Click "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".

The conditional formula to highlight cells with this criteria: 0.0X where X = 0 could look like this:

=VALUE(MID(TEXT(A2,"0.00"),SEARCH(".",TEXT(A2,"0.00"))+2,1))=0

**TEXT(A2,"0.00")** -Makes sure your data will have two decimal places.
**SEARCH(".",TEXT(A2,"0.00"))** -Returns the index of the decimal place "." within cell A2.
**MID(text, start_position, number_of_characters)** -Grabs a  substring of your cell, using a start number(determined by the search function), the 1 indicates how many characters it will return.
**VALUE** -Converts the text to string so =0 can be used to check for equality.

This will return true for values with 0.0X

For a formula that checks for this criteria: 0.XX where X = 0, paste two of the previous formula in an AND() statement and change the +2 after the search function in one of them to a +1 to check the character before 0.0X.

=AND(VALUE(MID(TEXT(A2,"0.00"),SEARCH(".",TEXT(A2,"0.00")**)+1**,1))=0,VALUE(MID(TEXT(A2,"0.00"),SEARCH(".",TEXT(A2,"0.00"))+2,1))=0)

For more information on the process of applying the conditional formula there is a [easy to understand tutorial here.](http://www.watterson-software.com/conditional-formatting-formula-rules/)